# Cpp constructor of a class that is inhereting

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

i've been dabbing abit with cpp after a long while, and i've had a wierd problem that i couldnt not find a way around.
i have a class called base message, with 2 kinds of constructors, a default empty one, and one that takes 2 arguments:

```
BaseMessage();

BaseMessage(int msgId, const string name);
```

i am now trying to implement a constructor of a class that is a child of the BaseMessage class like so:

```
CMicroControllerMainMsg::CMicroControllerMainMsg():BaseMessage(21,"s"), _data{ }
{
  Encode();
}
```

where BaseMessage gets an ID and name, and _data is a struct which i initialize with 0 at the begining. now to the problem, my IDE doesn't allow me to use the constructor of BaseMessage (tells me its an unresolved symbol), but if i use the default empty constuctor it does allow me:

```
CMicroControllerMainMsg::CMicroControllerMainMsg():BaseMessage(), _data{ }
{
  Encode();
}
```

so my questions are as follows:

1. why can't i use the constructor which takes the parameters?
2. can i circumvent the problem like in the example below?

```
CMicroControllerMainMsg::CMicroControllerMainMsg(): _data{ }
{
  BaseMessage(21,"s");  
  Encode();
}
```

Comment: why do you care what your IDE allows you to write? Seriously, its the compiler that has to compile it, IDEs can get confused easily. Do you get a compiler error when trying to compile it?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: "my IDE doesn't allow me to use the constructor"... you should trust your compiler even if your IDE has a problem. If your code compiles without any warning/error and the code works as expected and your IDE still report problems, you should update or change your IDE or simply ignore the IDE reports!

Comment: that's a fair question, i didn't know whether the problem was something wrong that i was doing or just the IDE getting confused. either way the compilation is done using a makefile, but i assumed that if something doesnt compile in the IDE than it wont compile using the makefile (they are both using g++ as far as i know).

Comment: You should proveide minimal example that we can reproduce to find your problem (at least, this class's declaration and definition).
But as far as I understand - you tried to compile your code and got "unresolved symbol"? Than this might be a linker error which means you forgot to implement "BaseMessage(int msgId, const string name);" constructor or linker didn't see it's definition